How is this Chrome attached to the PVC stub?
I am installing a new vanity after removing a pedestal sink.  Do I need to remove this chrome or can I connect the new pvc trap to it?  I wasn’t having any issues with leaks.
If the chrome needs to, or should come out, how is it attached to the pvc stub in the wall? Cemented I assume?
It might be wiser to just install a chrome P-trap but can that be attached to the plastic sink drain?
thank you in advance for your comments.


I wouldn't like to re-use old metal parts.  If you can remove that flange and take another photo it would help. Even if you have to cut it off.  If the pipe in the wall is PVC and your new drain is inside a vanity it's probably  a good idea to use a PVC trap adapter and all-in-one tubular drain kit.  If you remove the flange we can be more certain and hopefully tell you how to remove it.

That’s the thing- I am not quite sure how to remove this. lol There are no other couplings to remove so was looking for direction on how this comes off.   I replaced three other sinks in my house successfully but they were all PVC. Easy those were.  My house is 10 years old and I know the stub/drain in the wall is PVC but getting this metal pipe off from it is what I am hoping someone could instruct  :). thanks

Zooming on the picture, it looks like the chrome part might be threaded into the PVC stub.  Careful use of two rubber strap wrenches might prove this idea.

Push the escutchoen plate as far away from the wall as you can, and see if you can get a pic of the joint between the PVC stub and chrome extension.

It looks from your picture like the chrome pipe is in a threaded joint.  It would make sense because that is the most common way to do it and the only other way I can think of is a fernco, but that would be obvious.
You could slide forward the flange or cut it off with metal snips to get a better look and confirm.
Try to unscrew it
So, first, spray some penetrating oil in the joint, and wait a bit.
Then try to grab the right-angled part of the pipe and unscrew it.  It doesn't matter if you damage the metal part but don't break the PVC pipe behind it!  You, with a big pipe wrench, are much stronger than the plastic.
If that doesn't work you can cut it out.  This is not a lot of work, and it's easier than fighting with the threads for half an hour.
Cut it out
Saw off the pipe just in front of the flange and slide the flange off.  You can try to use a power tool for this if it doesn't shake too much.
Then, with a small hacksaw and by hand you cut the metal pipe from the inside out, along its entire remaining length in two places.   Be careful not to cut the PVC pipe past the end of the metal pipe.  Only cut part way through the metal ... stop before you get to the threads. It's like The Price Is Right: cut as close to the threads as you can but DO NOT touch them because you don't want to damage the PVC threads.
With that done, take large channel locks, grab the END of the pipe and  "unscrew" it again, but this time instead of unscrewing it should fold in on itself.  You could also try crushing it with the pliers, near the PVC joint.  Either way it should disengage the threads enough that you can work it out.
Finally, inspect the PVC pipe threads to see if you damaged them badly. If so you'll have to replace that joint.   A little knick here or there is ok but a gash through all the threads is not.

yes, 1/2 in wall. I have all pvc parts I need-trap, reducer . I just dont know how to disconnect this chrome from Stub since there are no other coupling nuts to remove.

I rewrote the answer to focus on removal.
